# Why can't Ubuntu see wireless?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

12.04 LTS

I just instaled Ubuntu on my Samsung Series 3 laptop. When the installation started from the dvd, it was able to easily connect to my wireless network, then during installation it's disconnected and when it's finished, wireless just doesn't work it cannot even see the networks anymore. Lists nothing. With cable I still can access internet but no wireless. It's a laptop so wireless internet is kinda important to have.

Please advise how to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have the WiFi drivers properly configured and installed in your recently built Ubuntu system, and from a root shell or with `su` (other privs might suffice but a root shell is the fastest reliable method to alter configs ), Linux shell commands and switches are case sensitive:

An instant "shotgun to the wall" method to determine if your WiFi adapter is properly installed but potentially just awaiting to be enabled is to do the following commands:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
ifconfig wlan1 up
```

If there aren't error messages, your adapter was disabled and needed to be enabled.

If that still fails, can you run `iwconfig` and copy/paste the output since it isn't terribly lengthy as your `dmesg` that is best served hosted at codebin.org

```
iwconfig
```

And look for a wireless interface likely named `wlan0` or `wlan1`, etc., that should have some description of your missing adapter.

Just because the installation bootstrapper managed to detect your adapter, doesn't mean the installed version is just as capable.

Comment: I don't think this is the most effective way of determining/troubleshooting WiFi issues. This question on the other hand: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into is.